# Should questions about flat rate time be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was about to answer the following question, and still will once I get more info from the OP. However it makes me consider if this type of question should be on topic.

[How many book hours would it take to replace a short block?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/16271/85)

[image]

While this doesn't have the same type of problem price shopping assistance has, the book time won't become obsolete but it's going to be a very narrow question that may not help many other visitors.

Should we have a general post or article on how to price shop repairs, or book time. I believe there are some good online resources for this already, but many if not all will be behind a pay wall.

Should these questions be off-topic and if so is there anything we can do to help out visitors of this site to first understand flat rate time and secondly how to make sure they are getting quoted the correct amount for the job.

Comment: If you do post up for @StevenEdwards, I would break it down ... as in, how much time for the block, for the A/C, for the cooler, for etc., then add them all up for a total. This should give a good idea of what others should expect from something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I would appreciate posts like the ones you described.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I don't believe ones like this should be off-topic, but I am one person. As you stated in your question, while this data is very narrow, it will not go out of date or become stale. JMHO, though. I don't have much more than that for a reasoning, other than I thought this had already been discussed before?

Answer (score 1):

Understanding that we are creating tags for models and nudging questioners for information such as year/make/model, answering questions related to book time for particular tasks on their vehicle are good for search engines.

The data points that are building up on particular models are very good for the site.

- year
- make
- model
- ODBII Error Codes
- Book hours for repair

To Move more comments link to top's point, this is now very refined information.  I will argue that the custom ODB codes for particular models are very refined as well.  If we are shooting for specific information on models and building that knowledge base then this maps directly to goal.

## If we know the book hours, let's share the information.  I believe it to be on-topic.

Comment: Well said, DK..